# writing a django query and get reverse related objects in one hit of database!

Tags: django-queryset

i have written these models in models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Skill(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    level = models.IntegerField(default=3)

class Work(models.Model):
    user = models.Foriegnkey(User)
    work_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
```

now i want to get those Works from database which their users have a certain skill, and render a html with them. i write this code in views.py:

```
def show_works(request, skill):
    works = Work.objects.select_related().filter(user__skill__title=skill)
    return render_to_response("works.html", {'works':works})
```

but there is another thing i want to show in that html: i want to show first_name of the user of that work and his skills. i used select_related(), but i can only show first_name but i can't reach user's skills.

i want to write an optimal query to get the works and the other extra informations, like user and the skills of it user! like the code blow:
( i don't want to hit database for every work to get its user's skills )

template works.html:

```
{% for work in works %}
    
        {{work.work_name}}
        user is : {{work.user.first_name}}
        which has these skills:
        {% for skill in work.user.skill %}
             {{skill.title}} 
        {% endfor %}
    
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably never look at this again, but I'll try to answer it anyway.

I would think that this should work:

```
{% for skill in work.user.skill_set.all %}
    {{skill.title}}
{% endfor %}
```